# WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration

Tags: c#, websocket, webforms, signalr

I have a websocket error when trying to use SignalR.

Full Error :

> WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration To
> enable this, set the following configuration switch in Web.config:
> <system.web>      </system.web>
> For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252465..
> at System.Web.Util.SynchronizationContextUtil.ValidateMode(SynchronizationContextMode currentMode,
> SynchronizationContextMode requiredMode, String specificErrorMessage)
> at System.Web.HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func`2 userFunc, AspNetWebSocketOptions options)      at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport.AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func`2 callback)
> at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestPostGroupRead(HostContext context,
> String groupsToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod[T1,T2,T3,TResult]
> (Func`4 func, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)

I've checked similar posts on Stackoverflow but my issue seems to be different.
Because, I establish connection with SignalR.

```
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var asset1 = document.getElementById('MainContent_MainContent_Asset1Hidden').value;
        var asset2 = document.getElementById('MainContent_MainContent_Asset2Hidden').value;

        var socket = $.connection.marketHub;

        socket.client.refreshSellOrders = function (msg) {
            document.getElementById("MainContent_MainContent_sellOrders").innerHTML = msg;
        };

        socket.client.refreshBuyOrders = function (msg) {
            document.getElementById("MainContent_MainContent_buyOrders").innerHTML = msg;
        };

        socket.client.refreshCompletedOrders = function (msg) {
            document.getElementById("MainContent_MainContent_completedOrders").innerHTML = msg;
        };

        $.connection.hub.qs = { 'asset1': asset1, 'asset2': asset2 };
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });

</script>
```

And I have WebSockets enabled.
[configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpYnR.png)

Additional code you may need :

```
 public class MarketHub : Hub
{

    public static readonly System.Timers.Timer _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();


    static MarketHub()
    {
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        string mAsset1 = Context.QueryString["asset1"];
        string mAsset2 = Context.QueryString["asset2"];

        string body = "{0}/{1}";
        string roomName = string.Format(body, mAsset1, mAsset2);


        JoinRoom(roomName);

        return base.OnConnected();

    }
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task result = Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
        return result;
    }

}
```

On Startup

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e, IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v2/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        });

    }
```

Web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="1234525324532" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Data is fine. SignalR is given correct data. It just doesn't update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I realized that I had SignalR 2.4.1 reference installed and I was using  2.2.2 .js file

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>
```

replaced it with

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js"></script>
```